# How to make keyboard not to popup on clicking of a TextField in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to get data into textfield from UIbuttons, but when the user clicks on the textfield, the keyboard popups and if I disable the user interaction textfield, it won't allow me to use `deleteBackward()` method, Used when user wants to delete a character of text field.

Help please.

Comment: set editable false instead of user interaction

Comment: and how to do it because I'm using swift 2.2 and it doesn't have that property to  textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create subclass of textfield and override `canBecomeFirstResponder` method.
To NOT display keyboard, return false from `canBecomeFirstResponder` method.

UPDATE

If you want cursor in your textfield when you touch it, juts assign blank view to inputview.

```
textField.inputView = UIView();
```

Comment: hai thanks for this. when i do this i won't get cursor on the textfield and can't type anything.

Comment: @pramodaravind Thats obvious. how can you type if you keyboard is not visible? You don't want keyboard right? This code will hide the keyboard and because keyboard is not there, you cant type. or I am misunderstanding it? Please explain.

Comment: i am trying to input the values to textfield from UIbuttons and only from that the textfield should take input.

Comment: @pramodaravind I have updated answer for this. Good luck, Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead of using deleteBackward() just set text without last character? This way, you can just disable userInteraction and get exactly same results.

Along with this, you can consider using UILabel, instead of UITextField

Answer (score -1):

put textField.resignFirstResponder() it will stop popup keyboard